# How to create dynamic dictionary names

Tags: python, dictionary

```
#!/usr/bin/python
count=3

for i in range(0,count):
    dict[i]= {}
```

Here I want to create 3(since count=3) dictionaries like dict1,dict2,dict3.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Anywhere you might want to write `dict1`, you can instead write `dict[0]` (though using the name `dict` is questionable, since it's the name of the type).

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos Later I will insert and append values(here i will take lists) to a single key value. And many other manipulations i want to further upon these dicts created here.

Comment: That doesn't explain why you can't just use the single dict of dicts as you've tried to do above.

Comment: not clear why you need that empty dictionary in advanced.

Comment: having a separate identifier for each of your #count dicts is very bad practice

Comment: you might need to lookup into setdefault and default dictionary.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

You can make somthing like that:

```
count = 3
for i in range(0, count):
    exec("dict%d = %s" % (i + 1, {}))
print dict1
print dict2
```

output:
{}
{}

Comment: why -1 and -2? if any one have another solution post it, if no so there is no reason to make these things.
if i'm wrong tell me the right solution.

Comment: I didn't vote, but this is **terrible** practice, and doesn't even work in a function, not in Python 3. In Python 2 it disables important optimizations for the local function namespace.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks, we are here to learn from each other :)

Comment: I'm actually having to create dictionaries from the nested dictionary that comes from Elasticsearch mapping and have to organize the data as I am doing some analysis based on what is on the first naming level that goes about 8 layers deep, so keeping them separate in separate dictionaries named after the names of the fields of the first level of the mappings is what I'm using this for.  I've dynamically named tables in a database before and as dictionaries can be looked at that similarly, I see no problem with this.  There are use cases where it helps.

Comment: This doesn't even work. `dict1` wouldn't be defined

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a bunch of variables. You can just use an array of dicts. You almost got it right in your code. Here's a correct version:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
count=3

d = [{} for _ in range(count)]

# Instead of dict1/2/3, use d[0/1/2].
```

Answer (score 1):

If for whatever reason you really(!) want to have single variables for the dictionaries (dict1, dict2, ...) then you could do the following:

```
>>> count=3
>>> for i in range(0,count):
...     locals()['dict{}'.format(i)] = {}
...
>>> dict1
{}
```

`locals()['dict{}'.format(i)] = {}` will add a local variable named 'dir{count}' and assign the value to it. `locals()`shows you the local variables and its values.

Remember: do this only if you really know what you are doing. Read please also the note on `locals` in the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals): "The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter."